# Google Play Select Devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I just finished making my game with Unity and I'm going to release it to the Play Store. I need to make the game available just for phones that have more than 1GB of RAM. How can I make the game available ONLY for that devices? Do I need to make this setting on the Google Play Developer Console?

Answer (score 1):

First, open [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) and select your game in the app list.

On the left side menu, choose **Release management** and then **Device catalog**.

[image: Open developer console]

Setup a filter. In our case, I believe you should filter devices with RAM < 1.0GB:

[image: Filter]

After that show device catalog as a list, tick "Exclude" checkbox, and press [SAVE].

[image: Exclude]

That's pretty much it. Hope it helps.